# redirect user to particular page depending on user role after sign_up rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am developing one job portal using rails 4.0. i have three user roles in my application that is seeker , employer and admin. if user signs up as seeker then he must be redirected to personal details form.

i have written following code inside of my application controller.i have tried this code after searching a lot on web.

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
  if current_user && current_user.seeker?
  redirect to seeker_infos_path
end
```

also i tried using registrations controller, but it did not help me.

Comment: is the method being hit? any errors?

Comment: nope. i tried it using binding.pry , but method id not getting hit :(

Comment: method is not getting called

Answer (score 1):

`after_sign_up_path_for` doesn't work if `confirmable` module is active.

If you have `confirmable` module active, you have to override `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` as a new sign-up is "inactive" until it's confirmed.

**Note**: If you are using your own `RegistrationController`, you need to put the overriding method in your `RegistrationController` instead of `ApplicationController`.

Comment: i have added binding.pry to check whether my method is being called or not but its not getting called

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps!